# Can the presence of Extended Spectrum β-Lactamases affects the action of AmpC beta-lactamases?

Tags: antibiotics, diagnostics, microbiology

**Double disk synergy test** (DDST):

> This method uses the cephalosporin discs and clavulanic disc alone.
> The principle is applying the cephalosporin discs next to the
> clavulanic disc with a distance of 20mm centre to centre. The
> interaction between each cephalosporin and the clavulanic acid will
> produce a synergy effect if Extended Spectrum β-Lactamases (**ESBL**) is produced by the isolate.

REF: WHO integrated global surveillance on ESBL-producing E. coli using a “One Health” approach: implementation and opportunities

> [image]

REF: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326583733_Distribution_of_extended_spectrum_beta-lactamase_ESBL_genes_among_Acinetobacter_baumannii_isolated_from_burn_infections

> AmpC beta-lactamases are specific to Acinetobacter baumannii

> AmpC beta-lactamases inhibits Cefotaxime & Amoxicillin but not Cefepime

> Clavulanic acid inhibits only ESBL but not AmpC

Is there anyway that A (In the figure) is AmpC positive?

Comment: I don’t think there’s enough information in the paper to know for sure. But strain B might have AmpC which provides cefotaxime and amox/clav resistance, but not cefepime resistance.

Comment: Do you suspect that this is some kind of defect in the paper?
I was suspecting that i might have missed a vital fact that causes this effect.

Comment: I just figured that 

[1]AmpC beta-lactamases are specific to Acinetobacter baumannii.
[2]AmpC beta-lactamases affect only 2nd generation cephalosporins and penicillins

Is there anyway that A is AmpC positive?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the AmpC